# I can't break blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I've been playing minecraft for a while. I stopped playing for a few weeks, and when I get back on in singleplayer creative and in servers it sometimes lets me break blocks and sometimes doesn't.

Why is it doing this? And how can I fix it? I've tried everything I can think of. Resetting my laptop, relogging into minecraft, moving sensitivity up. I don't know what else to do, and yes, my controls are correct. It's left click to break a block. But sometimes it will break and sometimes not.

Comment: Is this happening just in multiplayer? Or is it happening in single player too?

Comment: both please help

Comment: It sounds like you are experiencing lag either because of your computer, or because of your internet.

Answer (score 0):

this is a lag, mostly caused by less memory. Sometimes its in cause of plugins and the third reason may be a corrupted version.

I had a download failure once and faced that problem, too, but after reinstalling it it was gone.

Comment: ` its in cause of plugins` Nope, plugins are entirely server side (yes I know this is very old)